# Why subparagraph not inline with paragraph or section

Tags: sectioning

1. for the `subparagraph`, it is not inline with paragraph
2. why the content of `subparagrah` does not go to second line like others?

```
\chapter{Chapter 5}
\label{chap:chapter-5}

\section{section}
Testing

\subsection{subsection}
Testing

\subsubsection{subsubsection}
Testing

\subsubsection{subsubsection}
Testing

\subsubsection{subsubsection}
Testing

\subsubsection{subsubsection}
Testing

\paragraph{paragraph}
Testing


\subparagraph{subparagraph}
Testing
```

[image]

And for the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%  %for section paragraph
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%   %for section paragraph
            {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}%  %for section paragraph 
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}  %for section paragraph
\makeatother  %for section paragraph
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} % how many sectioning levels to assign numbers to  %for section paragraph
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}    % how many sectioning levels to show in ToC   %for section paragraph
%for section paragraph
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant package.

Comment: @leandriis, thanks. I done it

Comment: The information you provided so far is not a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). A MWE is a small complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that contains all relevant packages that are needed to reproduce the issue you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is under the assumption that the documentclass used is `book`:

With the `book` documentclass the default behaviour of paragraph ans subparagraph headers is the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{section}
Section text

\subsection{subsection}
subsection text

\subsubsection{subsubsection}
subsubsection text

\paragraph{paragraph}
paragraph text


\subparagraph{subparagraph}
subparagraph text

\end{document}
```

With

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
            {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

you changed the style of `paragraph` headers, `subparagraph` headers however remain unchanged. This can be done as shown in the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
%%%%% Change the style of paragraph headings %%%%%
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
            {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
%%%%% Change the style of subparagraph headings %%%%%
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
            {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}% 
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{section}
Section text

\subsection{subsection}
subsection text

\subsubsection{subsubsection}
subsubsection text

\paragraph{paragraph}
paragraph text


\subparagraph{subparagraph}
subparagraph text

\end{document}
```